# How to make custom Scroll Bar image and A-Z effect in contacts?

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-contacts

I am creating a contacts like application with a listview. I would like to use the scrolling effect in android contacts which displays A-Z in the middle of the screen while we scroll on the contacts list.Also i want to implement custom scroll bar image?

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this `API Demo >> Lists >> Array(Overlay )`[demo code..](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List9.html)
 it will help you..

Comment: Thank you Cap Droid..It was helpful.Can you update me on the custom status bar used in the contacts manager in ginger bread.